# R view lines based on specific values

Tags: r

I was wondering how I could view certain lines of data based on specific data i.e. good for viewing anomalies in results.

E.g. I have the following results from the command table(df$A)

```
     2      3      4      5      6     19    
143914  52194  30856  10662   2901      1
```

I'm surprised by the 1 observation where df$A=19. How can I see this observation easily in the console without having to make a subset (x<-subset(df, df$A==19)) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Great. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to just view the output in an interactive session, and you have no interest in storing that value, you can use `[` to "interactively" subset and view the result:

```
df[df$A == 19, ]
```